# I am getting the wrong image when uploading a picture

Tags: bug, status-completed, images

I have just tried to upload an image on Puzzling (although have checked and it is happening in both chat and on other sites) and it generated a link to a picture I have never seen before.

It doesn't matter what picture I upload, I get given the same image.

This is also happening for other people, so there seems to be a bug.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlR11.jpg) is the image I keep getting, and not only is it not on my computer, but I uploaded a completely different picture in this very post. However, I am now getting a different image when uploading something, and it appears to be changing every 10 minutes or so...

Comment: Can confirm. Tried to post NSFW to General, always got [a puppy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuGn5.png) instead. And a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CISYn.png). (and many different other images)

Comment: Note that only happens when you paste an image in the question/answer box, but not when you give an external link to an image!

Comment: Confirmed, by uploading a [screenshot of this webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBDdF.png); not even close.

Comment: I am getting a different image showng up: [Image Uploader Using Random Image](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8734/4301)

Comment: imgur is migrating stack.imgur.com to fastly, and something broke the upload, we're investigating

Comment: I hope they can fix the issue *fastly* ...

Comment: The obligatory https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Looks like the it's fixed now; I'm getting proper images.  Except for the one Dodge Hellcat.

Comment: @Ollie agree seems to be working now

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Imgur moved our `(*.)stack.imgur.com` image hosting instace from CloudFlare over to Fastly. Due to a misconfiguration they were caching the image upload API requests from our back-end servers for a while.

Kudos to Imgur for rolling out a fix before we did, we had an upload-URL-cache-busting PR ready to go.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Reproduced. This was supposed to be a screenshot of my browser showing your question ... It does look like a puzzle though :)

Meanwhile, I'm uploading my images via https://imgur.com/.

Comment: [That is my puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106691/a-puzzling-sudoku-warning-hot), coincidentally :)

Comment: o_O what are the odds ...

Comment: I used this exact image to try and reproduce the issue, btw. So it probably has something to do with what other users have uploaded previously (and by that I mean shortly before).

Answer (score 7):

I experience more or less the same:

No matter what file I upload, the image [`https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGfsT.png`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGfsT.png) is displayed:

[image]

---

---

I helped myself as follows:

- I browsed to the page [`https://imgur.com/upload`](https://imgur.com/upload) and uploaded my image-file there.
- The file got uploaded and the uploaded image was displayed.
- I clicked the image with the right mouse-button.
- A context-menu opened where by clicking with the left mouse-button I could select "copy image address".
- This way I had the URL of the image stored in the clipboard.
- I switched back to TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange and created the link to the image manually:
  Pattern in the window for editing  is:

  - Within the text:
    `[![enter image description here][⟨number of link⟩]][⟨number of link⟩]`
  - At the bottom:
    `⟨space⟩⟨space⟩[⟨number of link⟩]:⟨space⟩⟨URL⟩`

  `⟨URL⟩` is the URL stored in the clipboard.
  `⟨space⟩` is a space-character (code-point number 32(dec)=20(hex) in Unicode).

Comment: This is very interesting as I have also had this image before. Seems to be only a select few images that are occuring

Comment: Question is, for how long Imgur is going to store an image uploaded with this workaround? I seem to recall that images that are not uploaded in the stackexchage scheme and that don't get visited "enough", are purged after some time (half a year?)...

Comment: @Levente ... no? As far as I'm aware, we don't do that.

Comment: @Catija by imgur, not stack exchange. But stack.imgur.com images are exempt

Comment: @MartinSmith If imgur did it, we'd see tons of posts with missing images - as far as I'm aware, we don't. I'm guessing that our agreement with them includes perpetual hosting of images unless we explicitly delete them on our end.

Comment: the comment you initially replied to is specifically about "images that are **not** uploaded in the stackexchage scheme". i.e. by going to https://imgur.com/upload as this answer suggests

Comment: @MartinSmith Imgur ceased the practice you mention in 2015. Images uploaded since then aren't removed for inactivity anymore.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog thanks. Didn't know that. Some extra info here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/103297/205601

Comment: @Levente I hope, at the time when I realize that an image uploaded to imgur directly is purged, the image-uploading-mechanism via StackExchange isn't broken any more and I can edit my answer and re-upload the image. (I am mostly on TeX LaTeX StackExchange and .jpg-images are derived from the pdf-files that result from compiling the code-snippets exhibited in the answers and therefore can easily be re-created.)